# Alternative to polling Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We built a system where users are displayed new records in Elasticsearch. Our system had a backend Java client which polled the Elasticsearch at frequent intervals (30 secs) for any new data.

Is there a way for Elasticsearch to notify our program when new records are inserted into the database?

Comment: any news on this? in 2019? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment but there is an ongoing discussion in [issue #1242 (Changes API)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1242) that's been going on for... 4+ years now! A lot of people have requested this feature.

For the moment, I'm afraid you're left with polling, or you can check out the two following plugins and see if they'd work for you:

- [changes plugin](https://github.com/derryx/elasticsearch-changes-plugin): this one allows you to make a request and wait (up to a certain timeout) until there's a change happening
- [web socket plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-transport-websocket): this one is maybe more promising and adds web socket support to Elasticsearch, that would allow you to push notifications from ES to your Java back-end and/or front-end directly

Also depending on how your Elasticsearch is populated, that process (Logstash, etc) could potentially call a webhook in your Java backend everytime a new document is being sent to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @MrCholo Yes, this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579