# How can a Elasticsearch client be notified of a new indexed document?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, listener, logstash

I am using Elasticsearch, and I am building a client (using the Java Client API) to export logs indexed via Logstash.

I would like to be able to be notified (by adding a listener somewhere) when a new document is index (= a new log line have been added) instead of querying the last X documents.

Is it possible ?

Comment: One way to do it would be to instruct Logstash to call an HTTP webhook everytime it sends a new document to ES. Your listener could listen on that endpoint and be notified.

Comment: I prefer to not modify the logstash configuration, the tool may not be launched, and as I already have a client to ES, I would prefer to use pure ES api, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: https://github.com/ForgeRock/es-change-feed-plugin

Using this plugin, you can register to a websocket channel to receive indexation/deletion events as they happen. It has [some limitations](https://github.com/ForgeRock/es-change-feed-plugin/issues/17), though.

Back in the days, it was possible to install river plugins to stream documents to ES. The river feature has been removed, but this plugin above is like a "reverse river", where outside clients are notified by ES as documents get indexed.

Very useful and seemingly up-to-date with ES 6.x

**UPDATE (April 14th, 2019):**

According to what was said at Elastic{ON} Zurich 2019, at some point in the 7.x series, there will be a [Changes API](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1242) that will provide index changes notifications (document creation, update, deletion and more).

**UPDATE (July 22nd, 2022):**

ES 8.x is out and the Changes API is still nowhere in sight ... Good to know, though, that's it's still open at least.

Comment: Just got wind at Elastic{ON}Tour Zurich that this will be solved with the Changes API that is slated to be coming in the 7.x series. So I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is 2022 now. Any further solution for that?

Comment: @JamesFu Not that I know of ‍♂️