# ElasticSearch Alert on new documents

Tags: python, elasticsearch, distributed-computing

Is there a way to create alert whenever new documents are inserted into elasticsearch index?
I have seen some plugins on github but they are no longer maintained and last update like 5-8 years ago.

Comment: you want to have an email each time a new doc is inserted ? what's your version of elastic ? do you have any licence ?

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579