# How to bet notified when an Elastic Search Index has changed

Tags: elasticsearch

We have implemented a CQRS framework that projects document updates into Elastic Search.

We are looking for a way to be notified anytime Elastic has fully processed the update.

With Elastic we are able to wait for the update to complete (strong consistency) when we are performing an update but we would instead like to drop the update request into Elastic (not wait) and then be notified that this update has completed (eventual consistency) via a web hook.

Elastic has an ability to setup a watcher which currently only supports temporal-based triggers, as such we can setup to scan for changes at minimum, every second.

Using Watcher to constantly scan for document changes and to call back through a web-hook when condition has been met does not seem like a good idea.

It would be much better if we could somehow add logic within the Elastic Update Pipeline that calls through a web-hook to notify that the update has completed.

[image]

Is that even possible?

Comment: This thread might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579

Comment: Unfortunately the Change API is still not yet available.

Comment: It was more about the ES change feed plugin which works (yet only at the shard level)