# Is there a way to get notified of deleted documents in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, pipeline, ingest

I am aware of the ingest pipeline for ingested documents, or the workaround of marking documents as deleted / moving them to a different index with a rollover policy.

But is there a way to directly get notified and react upon deleted documents? (without making changes to the application side)

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579

Comment: Yes I checked it out, but it seems that this plugin is not maintained for the past 3 years, with the last release supporting ES 6.x

Comment: This was more about the Changes API... which is still cooking...

Answer (score 0):

at this point, there's nothing native to Elasticsearch that would provide this sorry to say