# Capturing Event in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Changestream we are able to capture all the events in Mongodb. In the same is their any option to capture events in Elastic Search. I need to manipulate Data inserted into one Elasticsearch index and need those in another separate index

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579

Comment: So there is no ES API for capturing events

Comment: Unfortunately not (yet).