# How to listen changes from the elasticsearch database?

Tags: elasticsearch, real-time, onchange, subscription

I need to implement the function like IFTTT, and make user creates the "If This" xxx "Then That" xxx. Most of our data exist in the elasticsearch and I need to listen to the data changed in the elasticsearch to achieve the functionality.

ex. if value > 10 for field OOO in index-A, then ...
ex. if the latest 5 values > 10 for field OOO in index-A, then ...

Is it possible in the elasticsearch? Or any further approach?

Comment: This thread will probably be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579

Comment: Thanks. In my application, do you recommend other service or platform to achieve it? In my application, each user can create different rules to get the notification. I do not have the good flow for it now.

Comment: Follow this issue and hope they will release it soon https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1242. Another approach, you can use some sort of database, listen to their transaction log , then sync it to ES for searching. An open source tool for listening to transaction log is debezium, I found a related article here, hope it can help https://debezium.io/blog/2018/01/17/streaming-to-elasticsearch/