# Query on maintaining the history missing document in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

If say i push a document that is pushed to the elastic search periodically gets deleted by the user.
what query in elastic search maintains history of the deleted document and inform the user that it was present and ow it hs been updated?

Thanks

Comment: This thread might also be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579

Answer (score 0):

there is no such way to know, you need to handle this in your application which pushes/deletes data to Elasticsearch, and once you delete a document that time, you can make another entry in Elasticsearch to track the delete request, in short there is nothing Out of the box in free version and you have to build the functionality yourself.

Comment: Just FYI, there's [this ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1242) that's been opened for like... 10 years... which aims at providing a solution for this, i.e. the Changes API

Comment: @Val interesting I don't know when its going to happen in Elasticsearch and even if they do chances are less that it will be available in free version

Comment: We'll see... :-) It's actually an opportunity that Opensearch should seize, indeed, but it doesn't seem like any work is being done on that either