# Moving older versions of documents to an history index when saving new ones (elasticsearch)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, document

I want to know if there is a built-in solution for something i need in Elasticsearch.
I want that everytime that my document is being replaced by a newer version of itself (with the same ID), the older version will not be deleted, but moved to an history index.
In that history index, I dont want replacments of older versions, but accumulation of them.
Do you know if there is a built-in solution for this, or will I need to program it myself in my API?
Thank you.

Comment: recently I provided answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73079487/4039431

Comment: So if i understand correctly, the answer is that there is no bulit-in way, not even for the paid version.

Comment: yes , there is long pending issue to implement it

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what do you recommend I should do to achive my goal? Should I change my Api so it will save my older document in the history index before it deletes it from the regular index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no in built method for your use-case, you need to do it yourself in your application, I don't think Elasticsearch is best suited for creating the history of a document as as soon as you update the document in the history_index you will loose its previous history and if I understand correctly you want to have the complete history of a document.

I guess best is to use any RDBMS or NoSQL where you create a new history entry of a document (document_id of Elasticsearch and its version number will help you to construct the complete history of your Elasticsearch document).

Above DB you can update as soon as you get a update on Elasticsearch document .

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be any built-in functionality for this. The easiest approach might be to copy the old version to the history index with the `_reindex` API, then write the new version:

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "your_index",
    "query": {
      "ids": {
        "values": ["<id>"]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "your_history_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx.remove(\"_id\")"
  }
}

PUT /your_index/_doc/<id>
{
   ...
}
```

Note the script `ctx.remove("_id")` done as part of the `_reindex` operation, which ensures Elasticsearch will generate a new ID for the document instead of reusing the existing ID. This way, `your_history_index` will have one copy for each version of the document. Without this script, `_reindex` would preserve the ID and overwrite older copies.

I assume that the documents contain an identifier that can be used to search `your_history_index` for all versions of a document, even though `_id` is reset.

Comment: Yes, I know this option. But I am trying to avoid it because I don't want to save it myself all the time. I want it to be automatic.

Comment: this will not work, as OP wants to create history on every update to the document, `_reindex` wil have to be manually

Comment: Maybe I Should change my Api so it will save my older document in the history index, before it deletes it from the regular index? But it seems like a clumsy solution.

Comment: @David even that will not work in Elasticsearch as Elasticsearch update deletes the previous version of Document, please check my answer for more detail

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast I know. But what if i first save the older document in the history-index, and only then save the new document in the regular-index? Maybe i could give a random-generated ID to the document saved in the history-index so they will not delete one onother. What do you think abot this solution?

Comment: @David yes you can give but than you loose the the `_id` of Elasticsearch and i am sure you want to construct the full history of Elasticsearch document later on and if you change its `_id` you will not be able to relate which history document belong to which Elasticsearch document

Comment: @David That is what my answer does: it copies the document from the regular-index to the history-index using the `_reindex` API, and removes the `_id` field to prevent overwrites in the history-index. I assume that you are indexing an identifier inside the document itself, not just in `_id`, so that you can search the history index for all documents matching a given ID.

Comment: @markusk I understand. But you do it manually, don't you?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast  I clould use fileds-values in the documents to relate between them. But still even the solution i presented feels like too clumsy. I would a thank you a lot if you could teach me a better way, if there is one.

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast I've read a little about "Elastic rollover". Could it solve my problem?

Comment: @David Elasticsearch rollover would not solve your issue

Comment: @David Yes, my answer describes a way to do it manually. The benefit of using `_reindex` is that you won't have to retrieve or regenerate the old version. The document is copied internally in Elasticsearch from one index to another without having to go through your application.