# Monitor changes in elastic index in real time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, monitor

I am working on a problem where I am suppose to monitor any changes made to elastic index in real time.

For example

If someone updates a document from

```
{
  "key" : "value"
}
```

to

```
{
  "key" : "value2"
}
```

I want to get notified for any updates made to previous docs or if a new doc is inserted in same index

Comment: Do you have security enabled and want to know which user is performing the change or only that a change has been performed?

Comment: I myself is making changes from an ec2 instance using default user elastic. I wanted to monitor what is being modified in an index in elasticsearch so i could make further decision making based on data i am receiving in real time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that [has been requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991876/how-can-a-elasticsearch-client-be-notified-of-a-new-indexed-document/51980618#51980618) for a looooong time, but is still "in the works" (i.e the Changes API).

In the meantime, you can leverage the [audit logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enable-audit-logging.html) feature, but it is only available with a Platinum subscription. You can still try it out for 30 days by [enabling the trial license](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/start-trial.html).

By listening to the `authentication_success` events and configuring request payloads to be logged with `xpack.security.audit.logfile.events.emit_request_body: true`, you will be able to see all requests coming into your cluster.

Once audit events are indexed, you will need to filter on `url.path: <your-index>/_doc/*` in order to only catch updates to documents of your index. You will need to figure out the difference by yourself, though.

Note that this feature is not meant for this specific purpose at all, but that's the closest you can get to fulfill your need.

PS: Also worth noting that the [audit logging feature](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/audit-logs/index/) is free in OpenSearch.

Comment: any luck with this?